# image_tag doesn't work Ruby on Rails 4 using Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

In my local environmental, image_tag works perfectly.
But in my heroku environmental, it doesn't work.

I saved images at public/imgs folder and refer it as follows.

\<%= image_tag  "/imgs/***.png", :width=>"50" %>

Browser shows crashed images when I open heroku page.
Do you have any idea?
I don't understand the differing of environmental.

Regards.

Comment: Do you have serve static assets set to true? If you include the `rails_12factor` gem in typically solves most problems.